# Reading lines from a text file and creating a text file for each name on each line

Tags: command-line, bash

Let's say I have a text file like:

```
john
george
james
stewert
```

with every name on a separate line.

I want to read the lines of this text file and create a text file for each name, like: `john.txt`, `george.txt` etc.

How can I do this in Bash?

Comment: Do you need the extension? There is no reason for text files to have a txt extension in Linux.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### #1 Using Bash + `touch`:

```bsh
while read line; do touch "$line.txt"; done <in
```

- `while read line; [...]; done <in`: This runs `read` until `read` itself returns `1`, which happens when when the end of the file is reached; the input for `read` is read from a file named `in` in the current working directory instead of from the terminal due to the `<in` redirection;
- `touch "$line.txt"`: This runs `touch` on the expanded value of `$line.txt`, which is the content of `line` followed by `.txt`; `touch` will create the file if not existing and update its access time if existing;

#### #2 Using `xargs` + `touch`:

```
xargs -a in -I name touch name.txt
```

- `-a in`: makes `xargs` read its input from a file named `in` in the current working directory;
- `-I name`: makes `xargs` replace every occurence of `name` with the current line of input in the following command;
- `touch name`: Runs `touch` on the replaced value of `name`; it will create the file if not existing and update its access time if existing;

```
% ls
in
% cat in
john
george
james
stewert
% while read line; do touch "$line.txt"; done <in
% ls
george.txt  in  james.txt  john.txt  stewert.txt
% rm *.txt
% xargs -a in -I name touch name.txt
% ls
george.txt  in  james.txt  john.txt  stewert.txt
```

Comment: how will `read line` actually read the line? @kos

Comment: @kashish `<in` after `done` makes `read` in the `while` loop condition read and store one line from `in` in `line` at each iteration; this way, `touch "$line.txt"` inside the loop will be expanded to the read line with `.txt` at the end.

Comment: will `while read line; do touch "$line.txt"; done <in` alone do the job?  Where is the source file?

Comment: @kashish Sure, they're alternative methods: you're meant to use either one or the other.

Comment: @kashish `in` is the source file, see the output of `ls` and `cat in` in the example.

Comment: +1 Though i don't understand how, but its working.  A good explaination will be nice.

Comment: @kashish You're right. I'm adding an explanation for both methods.

Comment: @kashish Done, it should be clear now.

Comment: how does the `line` variable know that it has to read from one line, and then from the next line?

Comment: @kashish that's how `read` works. See `help read`.

Comment: @kos Thanks! I got it. Very nice explanations.

Answer (score 19):

In this particular case, where you only have a single word per line, you can also do:

```
xargs touch < file
```

Note that this will break if your file names can contain spaces. For such cases, use this instead:

```
xargs -I {} touch {} < file
```

Just for fun, here are a couple of other approaches (both of which can handle arbitrary file names, including lines with spaces):

- Perl

  ```
  perl -ne '`touch "$_"`' file
  ```
- Awk

  ```
  awk '{printf "" > $0}' file
  ```

Note that on Linux and similar systems, the extension is optional for the vast majority of files. There is no reason to add a `.txt` extension to a text file. You are free to do so but it makes no difference at all. So, if you want the extension anyway, use one of:

```
xargs -I {} touch {}.txt < file
perl -ne '`touch "$_.txt"`' file
awk '{printf "" > $0".txt"}' file
```

Answer (score 7):

> Let's say I have a text file …

Let's say, I have an answer **;)**

```
awk '{system("touch \""$0".txt\"")}' file
```

Waterproof also with spaces and with a suffix **=)**

Answer (score 7):

AWK is also appropriate for this task:

```
testerdir:$ awk '{system("touch "$0)}' filelist

testerdir:$ ls
filelist  george  james  john  stewert

testerdir:$ awk '{system("touch "$0".txt")}' filelist                          

testerdir:$ ls
filelist  george.txt  james.txt  john.txt  stewert.txt
george    james       john       stewert
```

Another way, `tee`. Notice that this approach will break if a line contains more than one string in the filelist.

```
testerdir:$ echo "" | tee $(cat filelist)


testerdir:$ ls
filelist  george  james  john  stewert
```

Alternatively, `</dev/null tee $(cat filelist)` can be done as well, if you want to avoid piping

`cp /dev/null` approach (As I demonstrate this does work with filenames that contain spaces):

```
testerdir:$ cat filelist | xargs -I {}  cp /dev/null  "{}"                     

testerdir:$ ls
filelist  FILE WITH SPACES  george  james  john  stewert

testerdir:$ ls FILE\ WITH\ SPACES                                              
FILE WITH SPACES
```

Comment: @kos if each line in file contains exactly one string per line, then it creates a file per line. It's effectivelly the same  as `echo "" | tee file1 file2 file2` . But it does break if filenames contain spaces.